# solution for XMPP in iOS swift 3.0

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, swift3, openfire

I would like to add the chatting feature in my app by connect to my openfire server. I have gotten the openfire account and password for each user. I am looking for a direction, including frameworks or libs, to implement this.

First, I found [XMPP Framework for ios](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework), which is a well-done framework for XMPP, but built in ObjectiveC and probably hasn't supported swift 3. So I'm not sure whether there is any other better choice. This is the main problem for me.

Second, if I find a way to connect with openfire server (in step one), I could send and receive message via openfire server. I can use some chat frameworks, such as [Chatto](https://github.com/badoo/Chatto), to implement a chat feature by inputing data resource.

Would you give me suggestion about chatting feature in swift 3? Thanks

Comment: I have transferred the XMPPFramework to swift 3.0. The second problem is still under survey

Comment: I am searching the same Do you find any solution for it ?

Comment: Do you get any solution for that

Comment: Any Solution found ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use bridging feature for XMPP Framework to use Objective C classes in Swift.

for using bridging you can follow [bridging in project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/8023444)

And you can also follow swift chat project https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios